# Contact detection in sprite kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a game using swift. These are some basic rules:

- Coins in different colors are spawned on the screen
- If you touch on the screen, you will create a red circular shape. If that shape touches ( OR overlaps) a red coin, the coin will disappear.
- Neither the coins nor the shape move (isDynamic = false, affectedByGravity = false)

Can I use contactTestBitMask to check if the shape OVERLAPS the coin? If not, how can I check this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - assuming all of your contact detection is set up correctly, when you create a new red circle sprite and place it on the screen, if it overlaps a coin the the `didBegin(contact:)` method will be called.

Bear in mind that SpriteKit (SK) collisions are on by default, so unless you take the appropriate steps, the two shapes will collide and SK's physics engine will push them apart until they are no longer colliding so you may not see them overlapping and this may happen before a contact is registered (when I tested this by placing three sprites on top of each other, the contacts weren't missed but it might be possible).

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I found another way to do this by using "intersect".